# Dynamically load lightbox images (PHP, JSON, Javascript, JQuery, HTML)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

So i did **alot** of research on this topic..
I'm trying to make a **Dynamic ligthbox** which loads images regardless of name or **file extension.**
I'm using **Bootstrap lightbox**.
It works in **3 steps**:

1. **PHP** file parses as **JSON** file, which contains all images in specified folder.
2. **Javascript** fetches PHP created **JSON**, and creates **HTML**, in class gallery with filenames.
3. **JQuery** detect **click event** with **.on()** on images and gives lightbox image same **src**.

This works fine.. If i don't use **step 2** and hardcode HTML elements with source by my self.
If i then put my **fetch file** back, into the HTML, my **JQuery won't recognize dynamically created elements**.
Other Stack users have asked kinda the same question.
So i thought i might find some help in those, but the only thing i learned was that i should use **.on()** or **.live()** instead of **.click()**, and i didn't use **.click()** at all.

So i added some **console.log()**'s to my **JQuery**.
and i found the **bugger**, my **click event** doesn't run, everything **before** and everything **after** runs, but my **click event** wont recognize those elements **created dynamically**, or elements **changed by Javascript** by any means.

***EDIT:*** *The problem was  that i loaded  the images in after the Javascript have runned, for this to work i had to change:*

```
$('[class="thumbnail"]').on('click', function (event) {
```

*with*

```
$(document).on('click', '.thumbnail', function (event) {
```

***END OF EDIT***

**PHP to JSON**:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/json');
echo '{"images":[';
if ($handle = opendir('img/gal/')) {
$result = "";
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $result .= '{"name":"'.$entry.'"},';

        }
    }

    echo substr($result, 0,-1);
    closedir($handle);
}
echo "]}";
?>
```

**JSON to HTML**:

```
fetch('gal.php')
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            return response.json();
        } else {

        }
    })
    .then((json) => {
        var content = document.getElementsByClassName('gallery');
        for (var i = 0; i < json.images.length; i++) {
            content[0].innerHTML += "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3'> <a href='#' class='thumbnail' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#lightbox'><img src='img/gal/" + json.images[i].name + "' alt='..' ></a></div>";
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

**LIGHTBOX click event handler**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
    console.log('test1');
    $('[class="thumbnail"]').on('click', function (event) {
        console.log('test2');
        var $img = $(this).find('img'),
            src = $img.attr('src'),
            alt = $img.attr('alt'),
            css = {
                'maxWidth': $(window).width() - 100,
                'maxHeight': $(window).height() - 100
            };

        console.log(src);
        console.log('test3');

        $lightbox.find('.close').addClass('hidden');
        $lightbox.find('img').attr('src', src);
        $lightbox.find('img').attr('alt', alt);
        $lightbox.find('img').css(css);
    });
    $lightbox.on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var $img = $lightbox.find('img');
        $lightbox.find('.modal-dialog').css({
            'width': '40vw'
        });
        $lightbox.find('.close').removeClass('hidden');
    });
    console.log('test4');
});
```

My results in **console**, are as following:

```
test1
test4
```

If i remove my **fetch**, i get this:

```
test1
test4
test2
img/gal/asdf.jpg
test3
```

I hope anyone can help me, this is bugging me so **badly**..

Comment: why `$('[class="thumbnail"]')` instead of   `$('.thumbnail')` , i never used and seen class in jquery like this way

Comment: Actually it started out as data-target="#lightbox" and i thought it might was that which was bugging, so i changed it, forgot about it, but that part works fine, if i remove my **JSON to HTML** file

Comment: You can call javascript function from thumbnails onclick event. That might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event is not being handled, due to the elements the listener is binding on are being added later due to your script dynamically adding the elements.

To fix this you need to bind on the document and not on the element.

Try replacing this

```
$('[class="thumbnail"]').on('click', function (event) {
```

With the following

```
$(document).on('click','.thumbnail',function(event){
```